# Why does Hagrid say "cousin DON'T " instead of "doesn't"?

Tags: grammar

Hagrid:
If that dolt of a cousin of yours, Dudley, gets up to any mischief, you could always threaten him with a nice pair of ears, to go with that tail.

Harry:
But, Hagrid, we're not allowed to do magic outside Hogwarts.

Hagrid:
**I know that, but your cousin don't, do he?**

Comment: Doesn't* made a mistake

Comment: This is a very common property of many English dialects. It is not considered proper. If you search for phrases like "he don't", you will see it has been discussed here many times.

Comment: This is a very common property of many English dialects, and it is considered perfectly proper *in those dialects*, as well as outside of them specifically for the purposes of code switching. Shania Twain insists that being a rocket scientist *don't* impress her much, the Beatles inform us that she's got a ticket to ride but she *don't* care, and Sir Elton Hercules John, Commander of the Most Excellent Order of the British Empire, points out that the train simply *don't* stop there anymore.

Comment: And then of course there's the thing that Hagrid just does not exist. So anything he says is completely made up anyway. And it can be made up very poorly, or very poorly proofread, or both.

Comment: Of course,this is dialectal. I fail to see why code switching is relevant here. Hagrid is said to have a heavy West Country accent. Poor editing, my foot.